# Import a spreadsheet's area and import it into another spreadsheet's column

Tags: javascript, python, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet `SPA` and I want to group, sum and import its values to a column of another spreadsheet `COMPARE`:

```
... PRO DEMO    PSR PSDI    PRU UNPR    BLOCK   TUDORAN SIMION  
... 3   2       6   7       1   2       10      18      60
... 4   1       2   2       1   1       3       14      9
...
```

`Compare` would be

```
PARTY1 OTHERS PARTY2
379    ???    723
```

I know how to import such a column with `= IMPORTRANGE(...,...)` but no how to sum an area beforehand.

So far I tried to import the whole area in one column with `=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19_GB51MU2iUbs", "SPA!AB2:AJ19044")` but it's still `loading...` in the cell I imported it.

I f you have other solution like python or google script javascript I would be very happy to hear them.

Comment: Concerning that your importrange isn't working. But if you get that working, then you can wrap it in a `=query()` function to summarise.

Comment: I presume that your importrange doesn't work because of the amount of rows and columns involved. As @a-burge said, you could use the `=query()` function in order to do your calculations, or otherwise using ie. apps script. Could you please provide a bit more information on how does your data look like, and what are you exactly trying to accomplish?